# Sort Column Based on Another Column Order of Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns in spreadsheet1:

```
Col1  Col2     

1     PDC      
2     SR3      
3     PDC      
4     VBM      
5     VBM
6     GAL
7     VBM
8     GAL
9     PDC
```

I have 1 column in spreadsheet2:

```
Col1

PDC
SR3
VBM
GAL
```

How can I sort Col1 and Col2 from spreadsheet1 based on the order in spreadsheet2 Col1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code which seems a bit simpler and works great.

```
Sub NewSortTest()
    Dim keyRange As Variant
    Dim sortNum As Long

    keyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Range("A1:A10").Value

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=keyRange
    sortNum = Application.CustomListCount

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("A1:A20"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=sortNum, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    'if workbook2 is already opened
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book2") ' change Book2 to suit
    'if workbook2 is not opened
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xlsx")

    'change sheet1 to suit
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'change sheet2 to suit
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws1
        'change column B to column with your values "PDC", "SR3" and so on
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'change to address of range you wnat to sort
        Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
        With rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
            .EntireColumn.Insert
            .Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[-1],'[" & wb.Name & "]" & ws2.Name & "'!C1:C1,0)"
            .Offset(, -1).Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
        End With
        With rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
            .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    End With

    wb.Close
End Sub
```

**Explanaiton:**

1. There're two workbooks. Code should be places in first workbook (where you want to sort range)
2. The main idea is to add temporary column with formula like `=MATCH(B1,[Book2]Sheet2!A:A,0)` to get row numbers of values from column B (workbook1) in column A (workbook2).
3. Sort range based on this numbers.
4. Delete temporary column

[image]

**Notes:**

Next line assumed that column with "PDC", "SR3" (in workbook1) is last in selected range (`Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & lastrow)`):

```
.Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[-1],'[" & wb.Name & "]" & ws2.Name & "'!C1:C1,0)"
```

if it's not true, change `RC[-1]` to, say `RC[-2]` if this column is last but one and so on.

`C1:C1` part of formula means that in workbook2 column with "PDC", "SR3" is column `A` (column №1). If it's not true, change it to, say, `C5:C5`, which means that column is `E` (column №5).